# Invalid Variable Error for Solve When Using Law of Cosines

Tags: equation-solving, geometry, trigonometry, variable

I'm making a shadow simulator, and am using the Law of Cosines to calculate a certain angle in a triangle with two known widths and one known angle. I'm using `Solve` to do most of the heavy lifting, but I'm getting an error when I use it to solve for the length of the third side of the triangle. This is the function so far:

```
angleRequired[shadow_, w_, theta_, alpha_] := (
  (*width of the shadow*)
  s = shadow[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]] - shadow[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]];
  c /. Solve[(2w)^2 == s^2 + c^2 - 2s*c*Cos[180 Degree - alpha],c])
```

Right now, `theta_` is an unused variable. The variable `shadow_` is an "object" containing the coordinates that define the shadow. When I use the function with the necessary inputs, I get this error message:

```
newAngle = angleRequired[firstShadow, wi, newTheta, 50 Degree]
```

[image: The error message after running the code above]

I've made sure that `w`, `s`, and `alpha` are all valid numbers by inserting `Print[{w, s, alpha]` in to the function prior to `Solve` and got this:

[image: Output of the embedded Print function]

It's clunky, but all of the values in that list *are* numbers. I've also tried clearing the system memory before re-running the notebook with `Unprotect["*"];ClearAll["*"];`. Still no dice. (I included the apostrophes next to the asterisks. They aren't rendered by StackExchange)

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: If w,s, and alpha are numbers, then c must already have a value. Further,  shadow[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1] can be written as: shadow[[1,1,1,1]]

Comment: Can you also include the definition of `firstShadow`?

Comment: @DanielHuber yeah, the idea is that I'm trying to find that value using `Solve`. Is there a better way to get that value for c?

Comment: @Phillsy It's a pretty long definition, but just know that `firstShadow` is an object representing the shadow. `s` is the width of the shadow and `shadow[[1,1,1,1]] - shadow[[1,1,2,1]]` is the difference between the two edge coordinates of the shadow.

Comment: @DanielHuber Also, thanks for that syntax advice. You're right, that looks much cleaner :)

Comment: Have you checked that c has no value? It is dangerous to use c in the equation and at the same time to store the result. Use 2 different names.

Comment: @DanielHuber Embarrassingly, this was indeed the problem. Thank you so much for your help!